# Do flex-wrap break content in equal numbers?

Tags: css

This is a recurring doubt of mine, and I have been looking for a solution for some time, but I always end up procastinating and "adapt" the style sheet.

My question is, I have a list with several elements, and I want to make a grid with flex wrap, but when the content breaks, break into equal parts, if there are six elements, it will be three on the top and three on the bottom, if it is ten it will be five above and five below, from then on.

Every time I force this with `@mediascreen`, but I think this is not a practical way to solve this problem, and I'm looking for another way to solve this, it could be with grid junction or something similar, but the idea was to stop using it `@mediascreen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use these child properties for changing dimensions of elements:

Flex-grow:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-grow.asp

Flex-shrink:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-shrink.asp

Flex-basis:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-basis.asp

Anyway i don't know if it is possible to change spaces beetwen elements: you can try with margin of each element. (margin of upper row different from margin of lower row)